# How to implement dispose pattern with close method correctly (CA1063)

Tags: c#, fxcop

The Framework Design Guidelines (2nd Ed., page 327) say:

> CONSIDER providing method `Close()`, in addition to the `Dispose()`, if close is standard terminology in the area.
>
> When doing so, it is important that you make the Close implementation identical to `Dispose` and consider implementing `IDisposable.Dispose` method explicitly.

So, following the provided example, I've got this class:

```
public class SomeClass : IDisposable {
    private SomeDisposable someInnerDisposable;

    public void Open() {
        this.someInnerDisposable = new SomeDisposable();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        this.Close();
    }

    public void Close() {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            this.someInnerDisposable.Dispose();
            this.someInnerDisposable = null;
        }
    }
}
```

FxCop doesn't seem to like that:

> CA1816 : Microsoft.Usage : 'SomeClass.Close()' calls 'GC.SuppressFinalize(object)', a method that is typically only called within an implementation of 'IDisposable.Dispose'. Refer to the IDisposable pattern for more information.
>
> CA1816 : Microsoft.Usage : Change 'SomeClass.IDisposable.Dispose()' to call 'GC.SuppressFinalize(object)'. This will prevent unnecessary finalization of the object once it has been disposed and it has fallen out of scope.
>
> CA1063 : Microsoft.Design : Modify 'SomeClass.IDisposable.Dispose()' so that it calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize on the current object instance ('this' or 'Me' in Visual Basic), and then returns.
>
> CA1063 : Microsoft.Design : Rename 'SomeClass.IDisposable.Dispose()' to 'Dispose' and ensure that it is declared as public and sealed.

- How do I implement the dispose pattern with close method correctly?

-or-

- How do I suppress the warnings?

I tried

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1063:ImplementIDisposableCorrectly",
    Justification = "Framework Design Guidelines say it's ok.")]
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

but FxCop 1.36 still reports them.

**EDIT**: Changing it around as suggested eliminates all but this warning:

> CA1063 : Microsoft.Design : Rename 'SomeClass.IDisposable.Dispose()' to 'Dispose' and ensure that it is declared as public and sealed.

**EDIT 2**: CODE_ANALYSIS was indeed missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change it around.

Have Close() call this.Dispose() and put the logic in the Dispose() method instead of the Close() method.

------------------- Further info after edit ---------------

Also, changing the declaration to:

```
public void Dispose()
```

should get rid of the other error.  Since you have it declared as:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
```

It's not marked as public and sealed, and FxCop complains.  Personally, I prefer to get avoid the errors instead of suppressing them.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I suppress the warnings?

SuppressMessage() only works when you specify the CODE_ANALYSIS flag as a conditional compilation symbol.